# Missing Index Sysname

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I used SQL Server Management Studio to display the estimated execution plan of a query it will sometimes suggest a missing index.

My question is about the sysname in the following suggestion - What does sysname mean?

I would normally just replace the firstline with CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Users_Surname] so I don't understand the sysname reference.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Users] ([Surname])
INCLUDE ([UserID],[Firstname],[Email],[Password])
```

Comment: See [Using Special Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - for current versions, `sysname` is equivalent to a `nvarchar(128)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<name, type>` syntax is for the SSMS template replacement dialog, see [Replace Template Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230912):

> To use this dialog box, you must have parameters in your script
>   enclosed in angle brackets (< >) in the format `<parameter_name,
>   data_type, default_value>`.

Therefore `sysname` is the *type* of the index name template parameter, and sysname is the appropriate type.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Ive read that three times and the link you gave but I'm afraid I don't understand it at all.  Could you make it a bit clearer please?

Comment: Actually I just read up on templates and I do understand it now!

Thanks.